# Extracting items from List under condition

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of values:

```
f=[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
x=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
```

Now I want to extract all items from x, for which the corresponding item in f fulfills the condition

`abs(i)=1`

So I want to end up with:

```
1 10
1 20
1 30
```

My approach so far is:

```
for i in f:
    if abs(i)==1:
        for j in x:
            print i,j
```

But this gives me all items of x for every 1 in f:

```
1 10
1 20
1 30
1 40
1 50
1 60
1 70
1 80
1 90
1 10
1 20
1 30
1 40
1 50
1 60
1 70
1 80
1 90
1 10
1 20
1 30
1 40
1 50
1 60
1 70
1 80
1 90
```

Does anyone have an idea, which further conditions I have to make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> [(a, b) for a, b in zip(f, x) if abs(a)==1]
[(1, 10), (1, 20), (1, 30)]
```

[`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) returns items from the same indexes from all the iterables passed to it.

```
>>> for a, b in zip(f, x):
...     if abs(a) == 1:
...         print a, b
...         
1 10
1 20
1 30
```

---

Or if you just want items from `x` then [`itertools.compress`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) can be helpful:

```
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> list(compress(x, (abs(i)==1 for i in f)))
[10, 20, 30]
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate in pairs using `zip`

```
for i,x_ in zip(f,x):
  if abs(i) == 1:
    print i, x_
```

You might also want to consider using numpy fancy indexing:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> f = np.array(f)
>>> x = np.array(x)
>>> x[abs(f) == 1]
array([10, 20, 30])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
>>> f=[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
>>> 
>>> [ele for i, ele in enumerate(x) if abs(f[i]) == 1]
[10, 20, 30]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
 f=[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
 x=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
 tot = zip(f, x)
 for z in tot:
  if abs(z[0])==1:
    print z[0], z[1]
```

It makes use of [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip). It's a useful built-in that allows you return lists of tuples given multiple inputs. It kind of works like map() but it has a first argument of `None`.

Also, it is important to note that they inputs must be of the same length otherwise the extra indices will be left out. For example, if the input is two lists, one of length 4 and one of length 10, the result will be a list of tuples of length 4 and the last 6 elements of the second input left out.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your loop is printing the entire second list when it finds that abs(i)==1. I would probably do something like this:

```
for i in range(len(f)):
    try:
        if abs(f[i])==1:
            print f[i], x[i]
    except IndexError: #this means that x ended early
        break
```

This should give you the output you're looking for.

Comment: The other solutions are way better, but I guess I'll keep this here anyway.